# Encoding JSON with PHP issues with array

Tags: php, json

this is a simple question.. I'm trying to use leaflet realtime library, but it requires to load a specific JSON output such as:

```
data: {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-85.26995166666667,35.056891]},"properties":{"color":"#FFFFFF","route":"U"},"id":"118"}
```

so far this is all I got:

```
[{"type":"Feature","coordinates":["-34.66159","-59.42428"],"color":"#FFFFFF","route":"u", id:118}]
```

this is my PHP

```
    $id=$row['id'];
    $type=$row['type'];
    $lat=$row['lat'];
    $lng=$row['lng'];
    $color=$row['color'];
    $route=$row['route'];




    $data [] = array('id'=> $id, 'type'=> $type,'coordinates'=> $lnglat = array ($lat, $lng),
                        'colour'=> $colour, 'route'=> $route);

$json_string = json_encode($data);
echo $json_string;
```

This is driving crazy... I tried everything.. I read lots of json_encode tutorial..but I can't find an example or situation such as mine.

Please, help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to decode the `json` you need to create to see how the `PHP` data structure should look like:

```
$json='{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-85.26995166666667,35.056891]},"properties":{"color":"#FFFFFF","route":"U"},"id":"118"}';
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
print_r($data);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [type] => Feature
    [geometry] => Array
        (
            [type] => Point
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -85.269951666667
                    [1] => 35.056891
                )
        )
    [properties] => Array
        (
            [color] => #FFFFFF
            [route] => U
        )
    [id] => 118
)
```

Now, your code should look like:

```
$data = array(
    'type' => $type,
    'geometry' => array(
        'type' => 'Point',
        'coordinates' => array($lat, $lng),
    ),
    'properties' => array(
        'color' => $color,
        'route' => $route,
    ),
    'id' => $id,
);
echo(json_encode($data));
```

**UPDATE:** as @paul-crovella remarks in a comment, using `var_export()` instead of `print_r()` in the first fragment of code produces directly PHP code very similar with the one displayed above (except for the variables/values) that can be copy-pasted into your code and used by replacing the values (`'Features'`, `35.056891`, `'#FFFFFF'` a.s.o.) with the corresponding  variables (`$type`, `$lng`, `$color` etc).

Comment: don't forget that all of the data just be assigned to a single property in the main object: `$data = array( 'data' => array('type' => $type));`...

Comment: The text as it displayed in the question (starting with `data: `) is not valid JSON. I assumed `data` is the field name that must contain the json-encoded information. It is not part of the data but part of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
$id=$row['id'];
$type=$row['type'];
$lat=$row['lat'];
$lng=$row['lng'];
$color=$row['color'];
$route=$row['route'];

$data [] = array('id'=> $id, 'type'=> $type,'coordinates'=> $lnglat = array ($lat, $lng),
                    'colour'=> $colour, 'route'=> $route);

$json_string = json_encode(array('data'=>$data));
echo $json_string;
```

All I did was adding one more level into `array()`:

```
$json_string = json_encode($data);
```

Into this:

```
$json_string = json_encode(array('data'=>$data));
```

## Edit:

```
$data['data'] = array('id'=> $id, 'type'=> $type,'coordinates'=> $lnglat = array ($lat, $lng),
                    'colour'=> $colour, 'route'=> $route);

$json_string = json_encode($data);
echo $json_string;
```

OR

```
$data = array('id'=> $id, 'type'=> $type,'coordinates'=> $lnglat = array ($lat, $lng),
                    'colour'=> $colour, 'route'=> $route);

$json_string = json_encode(array('data'=>$data));
echo $json_string;
```

Comment: that gives you back `{"data":[{"id":1,"type":"type","coordinates":[42.565,19.6464],"colour":null,"route":"Route"}]} `

Comment: Thank you for reply! now this is what I've 

{"data":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":["-34.66159","-59.42428"],"color":"#FFFFFF","route":"u", id: "118"}]}

I need to remove those [] that prints after "data" and those {} and the beggining.. I tried str_replace but it won't work correctly

Comment: @JoshChisnerman: Cf all of the other answers here: this answer is probably the wors of all, because of `$data[] = array()` <-- this is what causes the square brackets in the JSON string. I explain why they're there in my answer. The simple answer is to replace `$data[] = array();` with `$data = array();` all of the other answers tell you the same thing

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the extra brackets there, therefore I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you again for replying.. I just have to little issues.. hope you can help me with those.

1st, it starts with {"data":{...  and I needed like this data: {.. without the {} and the beggining and without the quotes.. is that possible? thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$id = 1;
$type = "type";
$lat = 42.565;
$lng = 19.6464;
$colour = "Color";
$route = "Route";
$data  = array('id' => $id, 'type' => $type, 'coordinates' => $lnglat = array($lat, $lng),
    'colour' => $colour, 'route' => $route);

$json_string = json_encode(array('data' => $data));
echo $json_string;
```

Remove the `[]` from `$data`.

Output is:

```
{"data":{"id":1,"type":"type","coordinates":[42.565,19.6464],"colour":"Color","route":"Route"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!! 

That's good.. I did got that working.. now what I've to do it's to remove those quotes in data.. and remote the {} at the beggining. I tried many workarounds.. but I can't get it to work.. I hate PHP haha. Any idea how can I do that? thank you!

Comment: Then try this: `$json_string = substr(ltrim(preg_replace('/"/', '', json_encode(array('data' => $data))), "{"), 0, -1);`

Comment: awesome!!! thank you.. something I didn't say is that I load more than just one array... and with this code.. I mean without usin the [].. it will just load 1... what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Then you need to add your elements to an array line by line. You can not do this in 1 step.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
$dataArray = array('id'=> $id, 'type'=> $type,'coordinates'=> $lnglat = array ($lat, $lng), 'colour'=> $colour, 'route'=> $route);
$json_string = json_encode(array('data'=>$dataArray));
echo $json_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment to the `$data` array should look like this:

```
$data['data'] = array(
    'id'          => $id,
    'type'        => $type,
    'coordinates' => $lnglat = array($lat, $lng),
    'colour'      => $color,
    'route'       => $route
);
```

P.S. You also had a typo in the `$color` variable.